# How do I display only products that do not exceed the end date?

Tags: 8, views, entities, datetime

I created in my product type, a "Date interval" field.

I created a view that contains this field. With a start date and an end date.

I want my view to show only products that are within the end date.

I have searched in "FILTER CRITERIA" and I could not find anything to limit the results of my sight.

How do I display only products that do not exceed the end date?

Comment: Look under Advanced for Contextual Filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the views query alter (assuming you are using views since you have been wondering in the filter section).
A sample of it would work something like this :

```
function HOOK_views_query_alter(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view, \Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase $query) {

    if ($view->id() == 'YOUR VIEW MACHINE NAME') {
        $query->setWhereGroup('AND', 0);
        $query->addWhere(0, "Field NAME FROM Database for date", "ARRAY OF DATES FOR FILTER", 'In');
    }
```

Just Replace this with the keys for your requirements and it should work.